# trying to rdp into ubuntu

Tags: remote-desktop, xrdp

I just installed xrdp on ubuntu 15.04 using these instructions: 
http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=7984

When i try to rdp from my windows machine, it shows a grey window entitled "connection log" and it says "connecting to sesman ip x.x.x.x port 3350" but nothing else. (x.x.x.x = my ubuntu machine's ip addy)

It has an ok button... when i click on it, it just takes me back to the xrdp login dialog box.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

**What I've tried**
In the login dialogue box, i have a few different options for "Module".  The description above is what happens when I try the "sesman-Xvnc" option or the "sesman-any" option. 
When I try console, I get a different message:

it says:

```
  started connecting
  connecting to x.x.x.x 5900
  tcp connected
  security level is 0 (1=none, 2=standard)
  error - problem connecting.
```

Ideally, i want to connect so i have a desktop. I just tried command line to help debug the problem.

I'm not very good with linux but right now I"m just checking to see if the problem could be an unopened port.  Just googling how to do that. 
But if you have any other tips I'd appreciate it.

EDIT 1

One artifact i just noticed that when i choose sesman-Xvnc (which is the default module) the connection log shows 127.0.0.1 instead of the IP Address of my ubuntu machine.
Not sure if that means I missed some configuration somewhere.  This is different from the behavior I see when I choose command line.
Command line shows the right IP ...

EDIT 2

I selected the rdp-any module and it got further.  I specify the right username / password and then i see this:

```
connecting to sesman ip 127.0.0.1 port 3350
sesman connect ok
sending login info to the session manager please wait...
xrdp_mm_process_login_response: login successful for display
started connecting
connecting to 127.0.0.1 5910
error - problem connecting
```

On the ubuntu machine, i did "tail -f /var/log/syslog" and it writes out this record when the windows machine attempts to connect:

```
 Jul 19 10:31:54 myubuntubox systemd[1]: Started Session c8 of user testuser.
```

Comment: Did you enable "Desktop Sharing" on your Ubuntu machine? If not, press "SUPER" key (key with windows logo) and write "Desktop Sharing" and enable the option "Allow other users to see my desktop".

Comment: Yes, under desktop sharing it has both check boxes selected.

Comment: That protocol is VNC not RDP.  Also take care desktop sharing is one of the most common cracks so use a stong password. I advise you look into FreeNX, it is faster and more secure then either VNC or RDP. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FreeNX

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I'm just trying to install FreeNX but i'm getting error "W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/freenx-team/trusty/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found"  when i do apk update

Comment: Not sure about the ppa. If it is not maintained use https://www.nomachine.com/download which goes here - https://www.nomachine.com/download/linux&id=1 use the .deb

Comment: @bodhi.zazen ok i will give that a try but do i need to install something on the windows PC too?  Or just the ubuntu box?

Comment: You need the windows client . Last I looked it did not need to be "installed" as it ran on a flash drive.

Comment: nomachine is not working for me i think because of firewall policies... which i can't change.  So i'm retrying xrdp and i've gotten a little further... please see my last edit

Answer (score 1):

I assumed I could use just the default desktop in ubuntu. 
But i was wrong.
I installed mate like so:

```
 sudo apt-get install mate-core mate-desktop-environment mate-notification-daemon
```

And then I told xrdp to use it like this:

```
 echo mate-session >~/.xsession
```

And then i retried from my windows box and it works.

Comment: I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on Azure with resource manager. I have setup everything properly and I get a gray screen instead of any desktop :( Also tried what you have mentioned.